# Publishing to GlassFish 4 at localhost [domain 1] has encountered a ...., Cannot deploy abconlinetest

Tags: deployment, glassfish-4.1

I have no idea how step over this problem:
**After amending some code where Glasfish provide an reasonable error message i got this useless message:
"Publishing to GlassFish 4 at localhost [domain 1] has encountered a problem, Cannot deploy abconlinetest" without any other expanation. Even after removing my corrections to force Glassfish to produce the old error message is not possible. Glashfish sticks with this message. 
I got this message several times in the past and started always from scratch to set up the application step by step to get into a stable environment.

Below are the start messages from GlashFish.

> Glassfish stops always at: **2015-01-16T18:54:02.309+0100|Information:
>   HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final** Then the messages appears
>   thhat glassFish is unable to deply the application.
>
> Application uses JSF 2.2 writing the content of two formulars to an
>   Oracle database.
>
> 100|Information: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open
>   Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
>   2015-01-16T18:53:56.909+0100|Information: Server log file is using
>   Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
>   2015-01-16T18:53:56.987+0100|Information: Realm [admin-realm] of
>   classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm]
>   successfully created. 2015-01-16T18:53:56.987+0100|Information: Realm
>   [file] of classtype
>   [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully
>   created. 2015-01-16T18:53:56.987+0100|Information: Realm [certificate]
>   of classtype
>   [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm]
>   successfully created. 2015-01-16T18:53:57.159+0100|Information:
>   Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
>   2015-01-16T18:53:57.159+0100|Information: Registered
>   org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for
>   persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
>   2015-01-16T18:53:57.503+0100|Information: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15
>   started in: 47ms - bound to [/127.0.0.1:8080]
>   2015-01-16T18:53:57.534+0100|Information: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15
>   started in: 0ms - bound to [/127.0.0.1:8181]
>   2015-01-16T18:53:57.550+0100|Information: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15
>   started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
>   2015-01-16T18:53:57.565+0100|Information: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15
>   started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
>   2015-01-16T18:53:57.565+0100|Information: GlassFish Server Open Source
>   Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (1.346ms), startup
>   services(734ms), total(2.080ms)
>   2015-01-16T18:53:57.737+0100|Information: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15
>   started in: 15ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
>   2015-01-16T18:53:57.753+0100|Information: Registered
>   com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@3b0ee03a
>   as OSGi service registration:
>   org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@2bf94401.
>   2015-01-16T18:53:57.753+0100|Information: Binding RMI port to single
>   IP address = 127.0.0.1, port 8.686
>   2015-01-16T18:53:57.800+0100|Information: JMXStartupService has
>   started JMXConnector on JMXService URL
>   service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1:8686/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:8686/jmxrmi
>   2015-01-16T18:54:02.309+0100|Information: HV000001: Hibernate
>   Validator 5.0.0.Final

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

1. Go to Servers.
2. Expand GlassFish 4 at localhost [domain1].
3. Expand GlassFish Management.
4. Right click on your project name and press Delete.
5. Now run the Project again on Glassfish 4.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does not help me, same problem here

Answer (score 1):

**Approach1:**

Removing application from server

GlassFish 4 at localhost [domain1] Right click ---> Stop

Expand application list under server: GlassFish 4 at localhost [domain1]

Right click on the project

Select Remove

Click Yes

GlassFish 4 at localhost [domain1] Right click ---> Clean

GlassFish 4 at localhost [domain1] Right click ---> Publish

Re running project

Project ---> Clean

Project ---> Refresh F5

Project Run As ---> Run on Server

Select GlassFish 4 at localhost [domain1]

Click Next

Select the Project

Click Finish

running the project again, it fixes the error.

**Approach2:**
Same error, and the detailed error message shows:
cannot Deploy project: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

For TimeoutException errors, by increasing the timeout limit for server, will work: 
Right click on GlassFish 4 at localhost [domain1] ---> Properties ---> Timeouts ---> Start (seconds) ---> increase the timeout limit in seconds ---> Save
Run the project again with the same steps mentioned above.